# Como cambiar las vocales de un String por la siguiente? (la 'a' por la 'e' , la 'e' por la 'i' y asi sucesivamente)

Tags: java

LLevo rato con eso y no logro llegar a la solucion.
La idea es que si pongo: "Hola", quede: "Hule" o si pongo: "casi" quede "ceso"

Comment: ¿Que has intentando? ¿Cual es el problema?

Comment: Hola @Enoc, podrías agregar que has intentado hasta el momento y en donde tienes problemas? de esta manera la comunidad podrá ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendrías que crear un array que contenga las vocales en este caso.
Posteriormente tendrías que splitear la palabra comprobar si la letra es una vocal y encontrar el index en ese array y sumarle uno despues de recorrer el array unificarlo todo.

```js
const vocals = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
let exampleWord = 'hola';

exampleWord = exampleWord.split("").map(letter => {
 if (vocals.includes(letter)) return vocals[vocals.indexOf(letter) + 1]
 else return letter 
}).join("")

console.log(exampleWord);
```

También te recomendaría hacer una comprobación si es la ultima vocal para que o te devuelva la primera o se quede como esta.

Como no tenía toda la información no te he añadido esta condición

Answer (score 1):

Sería utilizando el método Replace

```
 String palabra= "casi";

 palabra = palabra.replace('a','e').replace('i','o');
```

Luego al imprimir el String palabra quedadía "ceso"
El metodo replace reemplaza la primer vocal que coloques, por la segunda.